# How to determine equivalence relation on a set of ordered pair

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, multisets

I'm new to discrete maths and struggling with Relations, need to test the following relations for equivalence on the set X also find an equivalence class if it is equivalence relation.

**Ques 1. X = R, x ∼ y <=> 2y < x<sup>2</sup> + 1**

**• For reflexivity**

x ∼ x <=> 2x < x<sup>2</sup> + 1

for x = 1, the statement is false.

=> It is not reflexive.

**• For symmetry**[updated]

x ∼ y <=> 2y < x<sup>2</sup> + 1

y ∼ x <=> 2x < y<sup>2</sup> + 1

for x = 1 and y = 5 in 2y < x<sup>2</sup> + 1

10 < 2, which is false

=> It is not symmetric.

**• For transitivity**[updated]

x ∼ y <=> 2y < x<sup>2</sup> + 1

y ∼ z <=> 2z < y<sup>2</sup> + 1

x ∼ z <=> 2y < x<sup>2</sup> + 1

similar to symmetry

=> It is not transitive.

**Ques 2. X = 2<sup>N</sup>, A ∼ B <=> (A ∪ B)' = N**

I'm not sure how to interpret X = 2<sup>N</sup> and check if it is an equivalence relation.

Comment: For the symmetry question, have you experimented with some simple (small positive and negative integer) values for $x$ and $y$? For question 2, $2^N$ probably means the power set of $N$, that is, the collection of subsets of $N$.

Comment: On the first question for reflexivity, $x=1$ (and only $x=1$) fails.

Comment: I edited the reflexivity. I still have to prove symmetry and transitivity.
So if there's even one value for which the statement is false, the relation is not symmetric? eg. for x = 1 and y = 5 in 2y < x^2 + 1 gives 10 < 2 which is false.

Comment: That's correct; you only need one counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2, $X$ is the set of subsets of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,N\}$.  $A$ and $B$ are two of those subsets.  They are related if the complement of their union is all of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,N\}$.  First use DeMorgan's law on the complement of the union to get ???  Then check RST.

Comment: (A ∪ B)' becomes (A' ∩ B') after DeMorgan's if A = {1, 2, 3, 4} and B = {3, 4, 5, 6 }, for reflexive, A ∼ A = {6. 7. 8...N}  ∩ {6. 7. 8...N} = {6, 7, 8, ... N} ≠ N. So it is not reflexive?

Comment: $A'$ includes $5$ in your example, but you are correct that it is not reflexive.  You should not say $A \sim A=$ some set, you should say $A' \cap A'$=$ some set.  The first is not a set, while the second is.